Use of subclasses of Generic in other classes
I am again fighting against the use of bound type variable in python.
Have a look at this example:

from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any

ParameterType = TypeVar('ParameterType')


class Parameter(Generic[ParameterType]):
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: ParameterType) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

# no mypy problem up to here

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._container: dict[str, Parameter[ParameterType]] = {} # error: Type variable "parameter_type.ParameterType" is unbound  [valid-type]

    def load_params(self, external_data: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        for k,v in external_data.items():
            self._container[k] = Parameter(k, v)


my_class = MyClass()

ext_data = {'a' : 15, 'b': 'string', 'c' : [1,2,3,4]}
my_class.load_params(ext_data)


This is an extremely simplified version of what I want to do in my code. I have parameter class in which the value can be several different types.
I have another class, not directly inheriting from the parameter class that is loading (from a toml file) a dictionary with key and value. These will be used to create new Parameter classes and they will be stored in a dictionary inside the class.
The scheme is working nicely and I have already used it several times, but now I want to do some static type checking.
If I run mypy --strict on the code, I get an error on the init of MyClass. Complaining that Parameter is unbound for MyClass and that I should make MyClass derive from Generic[ParameterType] as well.
Does this make any sense? In my project MyClass has a completely different inheritance and moreover ParameterType is the type of one parameter and not of all parameters in the MyClass container (in the example the first is int, the second is str and the third is list[int]).
The alternative solution would be to use Any:

class AltParameter:
    def __init__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


class MyAltClass:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._container: dict[str, AltParameter] = {}

    def load_params(self, external_data: dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        for k,v in external_data.items():
            self._container[k] = AltParameter(k, v)


my_alt_class = MyAltClass()
my_alt_class.load_params(ext_data)

but then I can also quit doing static typing.
Can you help me solving this typing puzzle?

A TypeVar must be scoped to either a class, a function or a type alias, but your MyClass is not generic and neither is its __init__. Potential duplicate: Type hint for a dict that maps tuples containing classes to the corresponding instances.
